# Comparing two tables in MySQL based on a common ID

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I'm trying to run a query that shows all the members of a customer that do not belong in one of their groups. I'm comparing two tables that have a  common `CustomerID` and using their member id's to show which members are not in the second table, `CustomerGroupMember`.

Here is a sample of the two tables.

Customer Member

```
    id  | CustomerID | First | Last
    ---------------------------------
    123 | 1234       | Jim   | Sample
    129 | 1234       | Julie | Clark
    137 | 1234       | Jack  | Thomas
    289 | 1234       | Sue   | Smith
```

Customer Group Member

```
    MemberID  | CustomerID | GroupID
    ---------------------------------
    129       | 1234       | 19
    289       | 1234       | 20
```

Below is my query which does not seem to produce any results. I'd like it to output anyone not found in that Customer Group Member table. In the table examples above I'd see an output of members 123 and 137.

```
SELECT CustomerMember.* FROM CustomerMember 
LEFT JOIN
 CustomerGroupMember ON CustomerMember.id = CustomerGroupMember.MemberID 
WHERE 
CustomerMember.CustomerID = '1234' AND CustomerGroupMember.CustomerID = '1234' 
AND CustomerGroupMember.MemberID IS NULL
```

Comment: Essentially change WHERE to AND and change one of the ANDs to WHERE. For further help, see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: yeah please show us some sample data, the output you would like to see.  it would be awesome if you add MCVE (create table statements with sample data).  you know what you're talking about, but we do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the second condition (`CustomerGroupMember.CustomerID = '1234'`) you are converting your LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN. All rows which have NULLs in the `CustomerGroupMember` columns will be filtered out, since NULL can not be equal to '1234'. You need to move that condition into the ON clause:

```
SELECT CustomerMember.* FROM CustomerMember 
LEFT JOIN
 CustomerGroupMember 
 ON CustomerMember.id = CustomerGroupMember.MemberID 
 AND CustomerGroupMember.CustomerID = '1234'
WHERE 
CustomerMember.CustomerID = '1234'  
AND CustomerGroupMember.MemberID IS NULL;
```

http://rextester.com/DLTQ86207